# What does the runway distance mean under "Additional Runway Information" on Jeppesen plates?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, declared-distances

See my previous question

[What are Runway Declared Distances?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21783/9491)

On Jeppesen 10-9 or 10-9A charts, there is a section dealing with **Additional Runway Information**.  Does these distances correspond to the declared distances in the A/FD?

[image: KFMN 10-9 Chart]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From page AIRPORT-3 (page 3 overall) of [this Jeppesen legend](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/intro-USA.pdf) (site jump-off page [here](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/aviation/business/additional-info-ifr-paper-services.jsp)):

[image]